# Can this sum be done without integrating?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, string

As by using conservation of mechanical energy, we can just be concerned about the final and initial position and the velocity could be found out. Am I not right?

But I am not getting the correct answer. Can I be made understood when to integrate and find out velocity and similar stuffs? And when just to directly use conservation of energy.

[image]

Comment: Hi Atharv, welcome to the Physics SE. Your question is not clear. Please review your wording, give a clear context of your question, show us, what you worked out yourself, and where your conceptional problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be done using conservation of Energy. The only point to be careful about here is that the change in potential energy has to be seen with respect to the centre of mass of the hanging object, as this is is a continuous body.

Also the potential energy of rope is only due to the hanging part of the rope, so the mass has to be taken carefully.
[image]

Energy conservation can be used anywhere keeping in mind that you are considering the work of all forces involved in the given system.